# How to dynamically create select with selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making `select tag` dynamically like this, what I want to make `third option selected`

```
var dropDownList = $('<select />', {
  'id': 'my id',                 // some id i want to apply
  'class': 'my class',           //some class i want to aply
  });  
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < myarray.length ; ++iLoop) {
  if(iLoop ==2){
    $('<option />', {
      'value': myarray[iLoop ].value,
      'text':  myarray[iLoop ].text,
      'selected': ??      // true/false
    }).appendTo(dropDownList);
  }
  else{
    $('<option />', {
      'value': myarray[iLoop ].value,
      'text':  myarray[iLoop ].text,
    }).appendTo(dropDownList);
  }
}
```

Beside i dont want to make like this

```
var selectElement='<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>';
```

Comment: put your array also here

Comment: there is nothing to do with array, what to do to select an option `'selected': ?? `

Comment: so that we can provide you example with answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute [`selected`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp), like so

```
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < myarray.length ; ++iLoop) {
    $('<option />', {
        'value': myarray[iLoop ].value,
        'text':  myarray[iLoop ].text,
        'selected': (iLoop == 2 ? true : false)
    }).appendTo(dropDownList);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atarasyuk/o2f8ok1z/1/)

Comment: @ozil. This function works by checking if the iterator is 2 or not. If not set the selected attribute to false, if so set to true. No separate if else clauses needed.

Comment: @Mouser it is doing what i want

Comment: @ozil, great because it's a good solution :-), that prevents overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < myarray.length ; ++iLoop)
```

If you are writing a for loop don't calculate array length inside the loop. Better to use as below

```
var myarrayLength = myarray.length;
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < myarrayLength ; ++iLoop)
```

don't compare like below. If array size is n than this comparison will be happen n times

```
'selected': (iLoop == 2 ? true : false)
```

It's more better to Use for in loop instead of for loop.

```
for (iLoop in myarray) {
    $('<option />', { 'value': myarray[iLoop ].value,
                      'text':  myarray[iLoop ].text,
                     }).appendTo(dropDownList);
}  

$("#time_entry_activity_id option:eq(3)").attr('selected', 'selected');
```